# How do I automatically start a new journal entry at emacs start up)

Tags: org-mode, init-file

Putting (org-journal-new-entry) in the init file doesn't work, neither does setting the scratch buffer mode to journal-mode.

Kurt Hesselbart's answer works only halfway if there already is an entry for the day, instead of adding a new one it opens the last. As the function description says:

> Giving the command a prefix arg will just open a today's file,
>   without adding an entry

However it didn't work at all without a prefix arg.

Works not at all if there is no entry for the day already, starting emacs with the -debug-init option then gets the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "before first heading")
  signal(error ("before first heading"))
  error("before first heading")
  outline-back-to-heading(t)
  show-entry()
  org-journal-new-entry((22041 37049 594411 222000))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/anon/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 7751
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/anon/.emacs" "/home/anon/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
#[0 "\205\262
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org-journal-new-entry` function has an obligatory and an optional argument. The first (and mandatory) argument tells the function whether or not to add a new entry, if there is already a journal file for this day.

The second (and optional) argument takes a value for inserting a specific time.

If called interactively, the value of the mandatory argument is given as prefix argument. If not called interactively, the value of the obligatory argument should be `nil` to be equivalent to be called without a prefix argument. Any `non-nil` value is equivalent to called interactively with a prefix argument.

The optional argument isn't necessary here, since it wasn't ask to insert a divergent time value.

Adding [`delete-other-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Deleting-Windows.html) helps to have the journal being the only window.

```lisp
(require 'org-journal)
(org-journal-new-entry nil)
(delete-other-windows)
```